# Bloomberg Excel API for Hourly Volume Data

Tags: bloomberg, excel

I'm trying to download hourly trading volume data via the Bloomberg Excel API. For context, this is the formula I'm using, which pulls hourly trading data for Apple between Dec. 10, 2021 and Dec. 17, 2021:

```
=BDH("AAPL US EQUITY", "VOLUME", "12/10/2021 00:00", "12/17/2021 00:00", "BarSize", "60", "BarType", "T")
```

This formula stops working for intervals that include dates before around Jun. 1, 2021. I guess this means there are some sort of limits to downloading.

On the actual Bloomberg Terminal, I was able to download data for intervals going up to ~240 days regardless of how far back the dates go. However, this particular formula stops working for dates before Jun. 1, 2021 no matter how small the interval is. As such, the restrictions seem a bit different between these two methods.

Here are my questions:

1. Does anyone know what the specific limits are for this particular
   Excel function I am using?
2. Is there an Excel formula to download hourly trading volume
   data with the ~240 day maximum like in the actual Bloomberg
   Terminal?
3. Is there another data source that gives hourly trading data for stocks (specifically Japanese stocks)?

Comment: Your friend here is "help help". With the terminal open, press f1 twice and ask away. Merry Christmas!

Comment: I'll try that. How fast is the response time by the way based on your experience?

Comment: Excel is less than 240 days (140 I think). Response time will be below 1 minute, an answer should be there within 30 min for sure for simple questions like this.